# NameNotFoundException: jmx-rmi

Tags: tomcat, jndi, jmx

Having an issue with remote JMX connection on Tomcat 7

```
ERROR: IOException trying to connect to JMX Connector Server: 
Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jmxrmi
```

I assume this means that jndi path (jmxrmi) is configured with an alternate name, and not jmxrmi.  But how do I find that?  How does the server indicate it wants to use a difference name?

I think what I am looking for is the correct JNDI path for that server's JMX RMI

Comment: What are JVM properties being used? What is the remote address used to access from JConsole/VisualVM etc?

Comment: The problem resolved itself - its seems there were multiple instnaces of an app running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple instnaces of the webapp running, which caused a conflict.